# Why doesn't my toggleclass work in firefox responsive design mode?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Im trying to make a simple animated button. My code works in a normal firefox window, but when i try using responsive design mode in firefox, the toggleclass doesn't fire, and always reverts back.

here is my code (https://jsfiddle.net/x6bxjwqL/) :

```
$(".heart").on('click touchstart', function(){
$(this).toggleClass('liked animated bounceIn');
});
```

it should work like this

[image: normal]

unfortunately

[image: responsive design mode, using iphone useragent]

whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: do `toggleClass()` more then two class as parameter?

Comment: your fiddle does not represent your problem. you will need to add your animation code to the css.

Comment: The toggleClass is executed twice: for both click and touchstart. If you remove touchstart it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you active the firefox responsive mode you have a button to emulate tap events. If you deactive this feature you are good. My guess is that the event is fired two times, one for the tap simulation and another for the click event.